# How to center block using position?

Tags: html, css, angular

I need your help. I have three parts of the page: `header`, `main`, `footer`. I try to center the `main` block so that it is in the center and deviates from the `header` by 150px. I'm trying to do this with `position`. The fact is that I can not center the block, and when I try to deviate from the `header`, my `footer` block disappears. Please tell me how to center the `main` block so that the `footer` block does not disappear and is always at the bottom. Thank you very much

html

```
<div *ngIf="fullArticle">
   <header class="img_header">
      <img src="{{fullArticle?.imageUrl}}">
   </header>

   <main class="article_details_content">
      <div>{{fullArticle?.title}}</div>
      <div>{{fullArticle?.summary}}</div>
   </main>
</div>

<footer class="footer" (click)="backToHomePage()">
   <mat-icon>west</mat-icon>
   Back to homepage
</footer>
```

scss

```
.img_header{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 217px;

   img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.article_details_content{
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%
   right: 50%
   width: 1290px;
   height: auto;
   background-color: brown;
}

.footer{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to use positioning for this, if you change the template a little, you can implement it like this:

html:

```
<div *ngIf="fullArticle" class="fullArticle">
   <header class="img_header">
      <img src="{{fullArticle?.imageUrl}}">
   </header>

   <main class="article_details_content">
      <div>{{fullArticle?.title}}</div>
      <div>{{fullArticle?.summary}}</div>
   </main>

  <footer class="footer" (click)="backToHomePage()">
     <mat-icon>west</mat-icon>
     Back to homepage
  </footer>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.fullArticle {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   min-height: 100vh;
}
.img_header{   
   width: 100%;
   height: 217px; 
}

.article_details_content{
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just opened a new account on StackOverflow and can't comment for now. But I wanted to some clarification on want you trying to do.

1. Do You want to center the main block horizontally or vertically?
2. What do you mean by "center"? Do you mean in the middle of the webpage?
3. The footer seems to only cover the bottom left side of the webpage; Do you want the footer to be on top of the main block and header even if you scroll?

#**Solution ?**#

It seems you want the header to be on the background and the main block to be on top of the header but the main block has to begin about 157px before the header end. So Here is the scss for that.

```
.img_header{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 217px;
 
    img{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }
 }
 
 .article_details_content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 157px;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: brown;
 }
 
 .footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Main block must me on the center and his and it should step on the header block with the picture. The distance between the main block and the picture should be 150px, so I use postition

Comment: Ok, the picture on the header seems to fill the entire header; so it's correct to assume that what you mean by "distance between main block and the picture" it means "distance between main block and the picture" ?

Comment: Yes, header fill entrie header, you are right. But it is question about distance between main block and header. Header is fathers block (postition relative), main - childrens (position: absolute; top: 150px). And this main block don't allow to center main block and closes footer block.

Comment: I just posted what I think is the solution. Is it what you want?

Comment: Thank you, it almost what i wanted. The problem is only, if we have a lot of content in main block, this main block close the footer block, overlaps it. How can this be fixed?

Comment: If I got it right, let assume the main block content is about 200viewport height( It mean you have to scroll the webpage to view the entire main block content) and because of that, the footer's content can't be seen? Is that right?

Comment: Yes. The main unit hits me on the footer, while closing it. If I remove the position: fixed property for footer, it will be lost. Please could you write me a better email to dcheyrnak10@gmail.com ??? Thank you

Comment: No problem, I just emailed you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean horizontally centered, you almost have it. Your styles position the left edge of your div in the center of the page now you just need to shift the element relative to its reference point using `transform: translateX(-50%);` this will shift it to the left by 50% of its width.
If you want it to overlap the header add a negative top margin.
Here's a working example:

```css
.img_header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 217px;
}

.img_header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.article_details_content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: brown;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: -150px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="fullArticle">
  <header class="img_header">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  </header>

  <main class="article_details_content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id laoreet mi. Nam posuere dictum odio non tristique. Morbi risus enim, laoreet sed viverra in, rutrum id tortor. Integer ac sem posuere, volutpat ex rutrum, malesuada sapien. Pellentesque
      laoreet leo elit, quis mollis velit pulvinar in. Nunc a vehicula ante. Maecenas tristique leo vel dui finibus aliquam. Phasellus rhoncus sagittis fringilla. Aliquam id est congue metus lacinia aliquet. Proin ultrices imperdiet tempor. Donec iaculis
      lectus ligula, in efficitur dui dictum vestibulum. Aenean scelerisque ut massa ut sollicitudin. Cras dapibus ex vel neque accumsan tincidunt. Integer in magna iaculis, laoreet ipsum in, semper massa. Suspendisse porttitor, justo ut porttitor vestibulum,
      sapien elit mollis orci, nec tincidunt turpis lorem nec velit. Morbi magna magna, ultrices quis elit ac, gravida placerat dolor. Integer faucibus vehicula velit non vestibulum. Integer mollis risus sed vestibulum pretium. Morbi quis lacus lobortis,
      egestas risus sed, venenatis eros.

    </div>
  </main>
</div>

<footer class="footer" (click)="backToHomePage()">
  <mat-icon>west</mat-icon>
  Back to homepage
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost what i wanted. Maybe i explained bad. I was meant that main block should be on the header block (should hit the header, the picture) and should be a distance of 150px.

Comment: So directly under the image, and what do you mean by "distance of 150px"?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZVuiYR7_7MAE8xGE9Q9UKp_i5wISPj0Z/view?usp=sharing Like that, header main and footer

Comment: Thank you. It works, but unfortunately when is too much content, main block closes the footer. You also can see it. How can fix it?